# Why does the USACO grader not accept my solution to "Prime Cryptarithm"?(Output difference between my computer and the online grader)

Tags: c++, c++11

I am programming a solution to the problem http://acmph.blogspot.com/2010/12/usaco-prime-cryptarithm.html

and when I run it on my computer, given the input data

```
7
4 1 2 5 6 7 3
```

My computer gives me an answer of 384 which is the right answer.  But when I upload it to USACO site, it says that my program outputs 1.  Why does this happen?
Here is my code:

```
/*
ID: harry47341
PROG: crypt1
LANG: C++
*/
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
vector<int> digits;
int a, b, c, d, e, abc, de;
bool oneof1(int n) {
    int count1 = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (count1 > n)break;
        else {
            count1 = count1 * 10;
            int digit = n%count1 / (count1 / 10);
            if (!count(digits.begin(), digits.end(), digit) ){
                return false;
            }
            n = n - n%count1;

        }

    }
}
bool check() {
    int n = abc*e;
    int n1 = abc*d;
    if (n > 999 || n < 100)return false;
    if (n1 > 999 || n1 < 100)return false;

    if ((n1 * 10 + n) > 9999 || (n1 * 10 + n) < 1000)return false;
    if (oneof1(n) && oneof1(n1) && oneof1(n1 * 10 + n)) {
        return true;
    }

}

int main() {
    ofstream fout("crypt1.out");
    ifstream fin("crypt1.in");
    int count = 0;
    int n;
    fin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int f;
        fin >> f;
        digits.push_back(f);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a = digits[i];
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < n; i1++) {
            b = digits[i1];
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < n; i2++) {
                c = digits[i2];
                for (int i3 = 0; i3 < n; i3++) {
                    d = digits[i3];
                    for (int i4 = 0; i4 < n; i4++) {
                        e = digits[i4];
                        abc = a * 100 + b * 10 + c;
                        de = d * 10 + e;
                        if (check()) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    fout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you hard-code the data *into* the program, instead of giving us a file to read (and write)?

Comment: Because there are many sets of input. Another set is 5 2 3 4 6 8 and the output should be 1.

Comment: The point is that if there is one set that gives the problem, put it in the program so that others can simply copy and paste the entire program.  For example, [see this](http://ideone.com/tWmGrD).  That is what you should be doing when posting the code, and not give us file names to read which we don't have.

Comment: Why do you use a static-lifetime `std::vector`? That is... not necessarily wrong, but it is a code smell and can sometimes cause problems. It would be better to allocate the vector as an automatic object in `main`, and pass it by reference to the helper function. My hunch is that you are getting undefined behavior by reading past the bounds of `digits`, but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `oneof1` and `check` functions, you do not return a value for all the return paths in the function.  Thus your program exhibits undefined behavior, since returning nothing from a function that returns a value is UB.  That's why you were getting different answers when run on a different computer / system.

To fix the issue, return `true` in the `oneof1` function, and return `false` for the `check` function:

```
bool oneof1(int n) {
    int count1 = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (count1 > n)break;
        else {
            count1 = count1 * 10;
            int digit = n%count1 / (count1 / 10);
            if (!count(digits.begin(), digits.end(), digit) ){
                return false;
            }
            n = n - n%count1;
        }
    }
    return true;  // this was missing
}

 bool check() {
    int n = abc*e;
    int n1 = abc*d;
    if (n > 999 || n < 100)return false;
    if (n1 > 999 || n1 < 100)return false;

    if ((n1 * 10 + n) > 9999 || (n1 * 10 + n) < 1000)return false;
    if (oneof1(n) && oneof1(n1) && oneof1(n1 * 10 + n)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;  // this was missing
}
```

Most compilers have a warning when you write a function that doesn't return a value for all return paths.  Please set your warnings to at least to the level that gives this information (or if you did, read the warnings that your compiler is giving you).

Comment: It worked, thank you.  I will keep in mind with return values from now on.